# Visual Studio - Opening a control reorganises designer.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

Just wondering if anyone knows the answer to this one. I am running VS2015, and some colleagues are running VS2013. We are all running our code through TFS for source-control, and we encounter this issue quite a bit.

When we open a form or a control, not even modifying it, then close it, it will completely restructure the *.Designer.vb file, but not modify any data (at worst, it's simply put the upper casing of True/False to true/false).

This proves an issue as we are becoming increasingly wary of working on the same forms as one another.

Does anyone know a potential fix to this, or if this is a bug of sorts?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is caused by VS IDE. And also not related to TFS or source control.

Comment: The reason I tagged TFS is purely because this is where the issue arises - when checking in code, we get changes on modules we haven't worked on simply because we opened it and closed it. It's a weird one :)

Answer (score 1):

The VB code use **PascalCased** keywords.Even though you write the keywords in lower case and VS would auto-casing to PascalCase.

However,there is a way to change to Lowercase Keywords：

1. Download [Glamour](https://github.com/AnthonyDGreen/misc/releases/tag/v0.1-alpha) from the GitHub repo.
2. Install it by drag/dropping the truetype font (.ttf) files in your
   **%SystemDrive%\Windows\Fonts folder**.
3. Change your text editor font in the **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors
   dialog** to **Glamour**.
4. Select **"Keyword"** in the **"Display Items"** list and check the **"Bold"**
   checkbox.

Finally you got this as below:
[image]

This method is referenced from Anthony D. Green's Blog. More detail: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2015/04/02/lowercase-keywords-revisited.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments   I was wondering anyone of your team are using the lowercase keywords cause this.

Comment: Hey Patrick, cheers for the answer. However, we aren't manually modifying the casing of the designer. It'll change on it's own, just by opening and closing a form or control. This then leads to issues with TFS, as the designer is no longer the same - and lately it's been rearranging controls in the Designer.vb file, and changing the casing only on the Boolean values (we always use PascalCase) - which is definitely a weird occurrence. +1 to your answer though as it may help someone :)